# SQL developer : Listener refused the connection

Tags: oracle

Dear stackoverflow community,
I know this question was already asked, but I tried to find a solution and unfortunately I'm blocked since 3 days now.
I installed Oracle 12c in Linux centos 7 server. When I try to access to the Oracle DB with SQL developer I have the following error:

> **Listener refused the connection with following error: ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor**

What I do not understand is that if I restart the database I can connect. But Once I disconnect a try a reconnect I got the same error. Here is my listener.ora file

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ns3008269.ip-151-80-45.eu)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

And my tnsnames.ora is :

```
 rspdata =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ns3008269.ip-151-80-45.eu)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = rspdata)
    )
  )

oraclepdb =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ns3008269.ip-151-80-45.eu)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = oraclepdb)
    )
  )
```

And finally you can fin in attachment a screenshot of my Installation configuration.

I tried lot of and lot of thing... but still blocked.

Comment: Are you able to connect to the database via SQL*Plus locally on the Linux box?

Comment: can you telnet ns3008269.ip-151-80-45.eu 1521? that will tell you the port 1521 is open between sql- developer  and database server

Comment: verify your local firewall , with iptables -L -n, you can stop it with: systemctl stop firewalld

Answer (score 0):

Hello Stackoverflow community,

I was able to solve this issue. I re-installed Oracle 12c in Linux server and I used the tools **netmgr and catmgr** in order to configure the listener for the global DBname and also configure the services for PDB. This will automatically will modified the listener.ora and tnsnames.ora.
So my conclusion is that when installing Oracle12c do not modify by hand the listener.ora and tnsnames.ora.
Thank you all for your help and for the tips.